# A function returning function without return type

Tags: swift

In a project I found a function was returning a function or calling it with help of return.

Although there is no difference in result but still want to know why we are writing return if calling a function inside a function in Swift why not we can call it normally or is there is any difference between them? For example:

```
func a(){
 print("In function A")
}

// calling from other functions

func b(){
 a()
}

// other way

func b(){
  return a()
}
```

Comment: `return a()`, that's `return Void`, so it's fine. And there is an implicit `return` when there is a "single line". Nothing strange here, but if `a()` returns a "real value" (ie other than void), maybe `return a()` makes it more explicit...

Comment: There's no difference between them, so the ```return``` is redundant in the second example. They're both returning the result of calling ```a```, which is simply ```Void```. A ```return``` statement is only required if the function has more than one line and if it returns a value.

Comment: I think you might be mixing up "printing" (putting text in the console) and "returning" (getting a value as a result of a function call, and handing it back to the caller)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the

```
func b(){
  return a()
}
```

doesn't return a function, it returns *the result of function execution*, which is `Void`. Since the returning type of `b` is also `Void`, it works fine. We could write both functions as:

```
func a() -> Void {
 print("In function A")
}


func b() -> Void {
  return a()
}
```

See [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/functions/#Functions-Without-Return-Values):

> Functions without a defined return type return a special value of type Void. This is simply an empty tuple, which is written as ().

To return a function itself, you'd have to change it to something like this:

```
func c() -> (() -> Void) {
  return a // <-- just returns the function, doesn't execute it
}

// Example:

let myFunc = c() // get the function to run
myFunc() // run it
```

Another interesting thing: you think that this definition

```
func b() {
  a()
}
```

just "calls `a()`", as opposed to returning it. But it's not the case:

> If the entire body of the function is a single expression, the function implicitly returns that expression.

So what you specified is actually an equivalent of `return a()`. If you had more lines in the function, then it would be "just called":

```
func b() {
  print("b")
  a() // <-- now a is called, not returned
}
```